# ORA-00942 with cx_Oracle

Tags: python, sql, database, cx-oracle

I'm trying to run any command on an autonomous database from oracle cloud after establishing connection but they don't seem to work.

```
cursor.execute("select * from admin.customers")
```

gives me the following error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\WORK\PING\OCP\dbConnect.py", line 49, in <module>
    cursor.execute("select * from admin.customers")
    cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I don't understand where this error is coming from as I can run the same command in the browser sql developper and it works, also haven't been able to find any real solution online

The problem might come from me not being on the correct schema but I actually changed it with this :

```
connection.current_schema = "ADMIN"
```

Thanks in advance for any leads !

(I am connected as ADMIN through python)

@GMB from the sql dev online I get 2 lines 1 - SH; 2 - ADMIN; and from python I get [('SH',)]

@AnthonyTuininga

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("admin", "password", "db201912040828_medium")
```

I'm using the db wallet

Comment: what does this query returns: `select table_schema from all_tables where table_name = 'CUSTOMERS'`?

Comment: Sorry, make it: `select owner from all_tables where table_name = 'CUSTOMERS'`

Comment: `connection.current_schema = "ADMIN"` doesn't change who you are connected to the database as.  Maybe the user you are connected as doesn't have access to the table?  I expect that you are connecting to the DB as different users in SQLDeveloper and in cx_Oracle.

Comment: While I totally understand your point I can't really understand how to change it, as I only have one user on my database and I'm sure I'm using the same credentials on both. `connection.current_schema = "ADMIN"` I know this only changes the schema of the connection, which was causing someone trouble so I added this to be sure I was on the correct one. Is it possible that I forgot to allow remote access or something similar on oracle cloud ? If not I really don't undestand where the problem comes from :/

Comment: Include the cx_Oracle.connect() statement, obscuring the password, so we can see how you are connecting to the database.

Comment: `connection = cx_Oracle.connect("admin", "password", "db201912040828_medium")`  I'm using the db wallet @AnthonyTuininga

Comment: up, @AnthonyTuininga any ideas ? :/

Comment: Perform a query: "select table_name from user_tables" so you can see what tables actually exist in the schema.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga I was getting an empty list so I recreated the table in the database and now it gets it... Sorry for being a pain ^^' weird things are happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreated the table and now it works

Thanks all for your comments !